# view data using ID in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, summary

I want to view another page using

```
Response.redirect
```

but considering a customerID along with it. here is my button code:

```
protected void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productids = string.Empty;
        DataTable dt;
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];

            decimal totalPrice, totalProducts;
            bool totalPriceConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text, out totalPrice), totalProductsConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalProducts.Text, out totalProducts);


            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text,
                CustomerEmailID = txtCustomerEmailID.Text,
                CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text,
                CustomerPhoneNo = txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text,
                TotalProducts = totalProductsConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalProducts) : 0,
                TotalPrice = totalPriceConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalPrice) : 0,
                ProductList = productids,
                PaymentMethod = rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Text

            };
            DataTable dtResult = k.SaveCustomerDetails();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // loop on how many products are added by the user
            {
                ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()
                {
                    CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]),
                    ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductID"]),
                    TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductQuantity"]),
                };
                SaveProducts.SaveCustomerProducts();
            }
            Response.Redirect("Admin/OrderDetails.aspx?Id={0}");
```

What it does is that it gets all the user input then in the end, i want to show to the user his/her order summary. As you can see, i am trying to use Response.Redirect.

The problem is i want to use the current customerID when i use the

```
Response.Redirect("Admin/OrderDetails.aspx?Id={0}");
```

any tricks on this?

Comment: Use Session Variable

Comment: can you give me a sample sir? please and thank you

Comment: why are you not able to add Query String? What is the issue?

Comment: i want to get the current ID when the button is clicked. so that it will show the data that is appropriate to that ID.

Comment: you are already storing CustomerID  value; you can capture that in a variable and substitute for {0}

Comment: how do i capture it sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111026/discussion-between-techspider-and-paolo-duhaylungsod).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `CustomerID` already.  Substitute `{0}` before redirecting with that value

```
var customerId = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]);
Response.Redirect(String.Format("Admin/OrderDetails.aspx?Id={0}", customerId.ToString()));
```